# Mapbox suddenly stopped showing place names, except for at a certain zoom level

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

While *yesterday my code was working smoothly and I have not modified it*, today **Mapbox suddenly stopped showing place names**, except for at a certain zoom level:

[image] [image]

Here is **my code**:

```
const tkn = document.getElementById('t').getAttribute('data-t');
    mapboxgl.accessToken = tkn;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'mappa', // id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11?optimize=true',
        center: [12.3424, 42.3011], // [lng, lat]
        zoom: 3.7,
        projection: 'globe'
    });
    map.on('style.load', () => {
        map.setFog({
            'color': '#8BF9EC', // Lower atmosphere
            'high-color': '#0ac2ac', // Upper atmosphere
            'horizon-blend': 0.1, // Atmosphere thickness (default 0.2 at low zooms)
            'space-color': '#011311',
        });
        // Set map in Italian:
        map.getStyle().layers.forEach(function(thisLayer){
            if(thisLayer.type == 'symbol'){
                map.setLayoutProperty(thisLayer.id, 'text-field', ['get','name_it'])
            };
        });
        //
    });
```

What can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out? Running into similar issues.

Comment: @StephenWatkins Sorry, it was not so crucial for my app, so I later on did not continue trying to solve this problem. I hope it does not hamper your app too much, but if it does, perhaps you'd better try to contact Mapbox support (if possible). All the best!